# OIDC Application logging

Tags: azure-active-directory

Applications registered through AAD (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-app-registration) are provisioned a client id and secret to access Azure resources via the MS Graph REST API using an Oauth flow.

There are currently no logs for these calls being emitted to the AAD sign-in or audit logs. I am not currently aware of any endpoint where I can obtain these external calls.

This means that if a client secret was ever leaked, I have no way to identify that there are calls being made.

I would like to see activities related to registered application/service principal:

•   Event that shows when users register/change/remove AAD applications

•   AAD application authentication events

As a POC, I have tried registering an application from App registration module and tried creating client ID and Secret but did not find any relevant audit logs for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the **audit report**, you should be the Security Admininistrator, Security Reader or Global Administrator roles. 
All users (non-administrators) can only see their own audit activities. You could read this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs) to know the details.

In my audit logs, I could get all the changes like the following:

[image]

About **Sign-in** activity reports. The sign-in user should be the Security Administrator, Security Reader, Report Reader role, or Global Administrator. 
Any user (non-admins) can only access their own sign-ins. And your tenant must have an Azure AD Premium license associated with it. For the details, please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-sign-ins).

And the information about the sign-in likes this:

[image]

> Note: The sign-ins report only displays the interactive sign-ins, that
>   is, sign-ins where a user manually signs in using their username and
>   password. Non-interactive sign-ins, such as service-to-service
>   authentication, are not displayed in the sign-ins report.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test this at my end.

Comment: @YuvrajKukar, if there is anything update, please feel free to let me know, thanks!

Comment: I have verified that and confirm the changes you have mentioned are recorded in Audit Log.
On the other hand, I am still not seeing app authentication event in SignIn Log. I am expecting to see an application authentication event in SignIn, that shows the appId was used successfully. However, I am not seeing any event in the SignIn Logs.

Comment: @YuvrajKukar, I already update my answer here, please take a look. For the service to service authentication, I tried the client credentials, It indeed cannot display in the sign-ins.

Comment: @YuvrajKukar, if there is anything update, please let me know. And if it is useful for you, please help make a mark, thanks.